# Currency symbol: Turkish Lira

Tags: symbols

I have two questions.

1. Is there a single currency package containing the most common currency symbols, such as dollar, euro, frank, pound (sterling), yen, peso, etc.
2. I couldn't find the currency symbol of Turkey in LaTeX. How can we make a Turkish Lira symbol for LaTeX? [This is what the Turkish Lira symbol looks like](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosya:Turkish_lira_symbol_black.svg)

[image]

and its technical details are [here](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosya:TL-Simge-olculeri.jpg). In addition, its unicode encoding is U+20BA .

I will be very happy if some one construct this sign as a LaTeX code without using external graphics, or explains me how to construct it.

Comment: The symbol can be seen on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira_sign#mediaviewer/File:Turkish_Lira_Construction.svg).

Comment: With plain-format: `\chardef\tlira="20BA`. Needs a font which has it (seems rare, Symbola has it), and a Unicode-aware engine (XeTeX, LuaTeX). With LaTeX there was some command like `\declareUnicodesomethingsomething` sorry can't remember.

Comment: It's not relevant but I hope this abomination will die before it catches up. It's the ugliest and tasteless thing about a currency.

Answer (score 8):

With `tikz` and little bit of cheating (i.e., using `inkscape2tikz`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Lira}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.08em, y=0.08em, xscale=0.03, yscale=-0.03, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\fill (54.3355,9.3092) .. controls (70.3869,9.3092) and (79.7110,9.3092) ..
  (82.3075,9.3092) .. controls (82.3075,12.1418) and (82.3075,24.2985) ..
  (82.3075,45.7791) .. controls (82.3075,67.2598) and (82.3075,79.2984) ..
  (82.3075,81.8950) -- (167.2860,51.0903) .. controls (167.2860,59.3521) and
  (167.2860,66.7877) .. (167.2860,73.3971) -- (82.3075,104.2018) .. controls
  (82.3075,105.1460) and (82.3075,107.1525) .. (82.3075,110.2211) .. controls
  (82.3075,113.2898) and (82.3075,115.2962) .. (82.3075,116.2404) --
  (128.3375,99.9529) -- (167.2860,85.4358) .. controls (167.2860,86.8521) and
  (167.2860,90.4518) .. (167.2860,96.2351) .. controls (167.2860,102.0184) and
  (167.2860,105.5001) .. (167.2860,106.6804) .. controls (167.2860,107.6246) and
  (167.0499,108.0967) .. (166.5778,108.0967) -- (84.7861,137.4851) .. controls
  (83.8419,137.9572) and (83.0157,138.4293) .. (82.3075,138.9014) .. controls
  (82.3075,153.3005) and (82.3075,173.1878) .. (82.3075,198.5633) .. controls
  (82.3075,223.9388) and (82.3075,243.8262) .. (82.3075,258.2253) .. controls
  (82.3075,258.2253) and (82.3075,258.3433) .. (82.3075,258.5794) .. controls
  (82.3075,258.8154) and (82.3075,258.9334) .. (82.3075,258.9334) .. controls
  (103.7882,256.3369) and (122.7903,248.1931) .. (139.3139,234.5021) .. controls
  (157.4899,219.6309) and (169.6465,201.1009) .. (175.7838,178.9121) .. controls
  (178.3804,168.7619) and (179.6787,158.6117) .. (179.6787,148.4614) .. controls
  (179.6787,148.4614) and (189.1207,148.4614) .. (208.0048,148.4614) .. controls
  (208.0048,171.3584) and (202.4576,192.9571) .. (191.3632,213.2575) .. controls
  (183.5735,228.8369) and (172.9512,242.2918) .. (159.4963,253.6223) .. controls
  (146.9856,264.7167) and (132.9405,273.2145) .. (117.3611,279.1158) .. controls
  (97.0607,286.9055) and (76.0522,289.6201) .. (54.3355,287.2596) .. controls
  (54.3355,271.9163) and (54.3355,248.9013) .. (54.3355,218.2146) .. controls
  (54.3355,187.5279) and (54.3355,164.3949) .. (54.3355,148.8155) .. controls
  (54.3355,148.8155) and (52.8011,149.4057) .. (49.7325,150.5859) --
  (1.2239,167.9357) .. controls (1.2239,160.8541) and (1.2239,153.4185) ..
  (1.2239,145.6288) -- (54.3355,126.5087) .. controls (54.3355,125.0924) and
  (54.3355,120.9615) .. (54.3355,114.1160) .. controls (51.7389,115.2962) and
  (48.2571,116.7126) .. (43.8902,118.3649) .. controls (39.5232,120.0173) and
  (36.7496,120.9615) .. (35.5694,121.1975) -- (7.5973,131.4658) .. controls
  (7.5973,131.4658) and (6.8301,131.7018) .. (5.2958,132.1739) .. controls
  (3.7615,132.6460) and (2.4042,133.0001) .. (1.2239,133.2361) .. controls
  (1.2239,121.9057) and (1.2239,114.4701) .. (1.2239,110.9293) --
  (54.3355,92.1632) .. controls (54.3355,81.7770) and (54.3355,67.9680) ..
  (54.3355,50.7362) .. controls (54.3355,33.5045) and (54.3355,19.6955) ..
  (54.3355,9.3092) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}
  This will cost you 10\Lira.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The symbol exists in FontAwesome icons:

[image]

There exists a LaTeX package called `fontawesome` that gives a convenient interface to the FontAwesome icons. Unfortunately, it is based on version 3.xxx of these icons, and this symbol is in the font since version 4.0. I'll probably try to complete the package if the author doesn't, but not before a few weeks. For the time being, you can use it with Xe/LuaLaTeX.

On [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ba/fontsupport.htm), you'll find a list of fonts that support the turkish-lira. A number of these have support in LaTeX (`DejaVu`, `SourceCode Pro`, `SourceSans Pro`).

Answer (score 2):

1. I do not know a package which defines the most common currency signs. I would just search a font which has them all. You may want to search the unicode of the existing symbols first: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm
2. Here is the Turkish symbol with use of its unicode (and `siunitx`):

   ```
   % arara: lualatex

   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \DeclareSIUnit\turkishLira{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\text{\symbol{"20BA}}}}

   \begin{document}
       \SI{1000000}{\turkishLira}

       \setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"20BA}
       \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"20BA}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]